# How to verify that file is downloaded in testcafe?

Tags: typescript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Suppose we have a file to download and we have to verify that file is downloaded
so first you have to download the file and then verify that file is in the folder.

Answer (score 1):

```
     const download_Image_Btn= XPathSelector("//*[text()='Download']")
     const download_Png_image= XPathSelector("//li[text()='Download PNG image']")
     const download_jpg_image= XPathSelector("//li[text()='Download JPEG image']")
     const download_pdf_image= XPathSelector("//li[text()='Download PDF document']")
     const fileNamepng = 'chart.png'
     const fileNamejpg = 'chart.jpeg'
     const fileNamepdf = 'chart.pdf'
     const downloadLocation = '/Users/xddsd/Downloads/'; //download location in system
     await t 
            .click(download_Image_Btn)     //clicked on the link
            .click(download_Png_image)     //downloaded the file
     await t.expect(fs.existsSync(downloadLocation + fileNamepng)).ok();
```

Comment: You can also take a look at the following answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57582108/testcafe-example-to-assert-file-download

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it. The actual example is always available in the [TestCafe Examples repo](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-examples/blob/master/examples/check-downloaded-file-name-and-content/index.js).

```
import { RequestLogger } from 'testcafe';

const url = 'http://localhost:3000/download-file';

const logger = RequestLogger({ url, method: 'GET' }, {
    logResponseHeaders:     true,
    logResponseBody:        true,
    stringifyResponseBody:  true
});

fixture `Download file`
    .page('./index.html')
    .requestHooks(logger);

test('Check file name and content', async t => {
    const fileNameRegEx = /attachment; filename=.*.txt/;
    
    await t
        .click('#download-btn')
        .expect(logger.contains(r => {
            if (r.response.statusCode !== 200)
                return false;
           
            const requestInfo = logger.requests[0];
           
            if (!requestInfo)
                return false;
      
            const downloadedFileName = requestInfo.response.headers['content-disposition'];
            
            if (!downloadedFileName)
                false;
      
             if (!fileNameRegEx.test(downloadedFileName))
                  return false;
            
             const downloadedFileContent = logger.requests[0].response.body;
      
             return downloadedFileContent  === 'Test content';
      })).ok();
});
```