# testCafe --Unable to get the content of the exported file

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Business scenario: Click the button to export the content of the table as an Excel file. I need to test whether the data in the table is equal to the content of Excel. It is enough to judge that the number of entries is the same. Of course, other methods are also available.

Looking forward to reply, thanks a lot!

Unable to get the content of the exported file

Answer (score 0):

You can check the file content using the RequestHooks mechanism: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-examples/tree/master/examples/check-downloaded-file-name-and-content.

Alternatively, open the downloaded file from the test. Please refer to the following thread: [Testcafe example to assert file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57582108/testcafe-example-to-assert-file-download).

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your reply, but I am not downloading from the server, but exporting the data rendered by the table.

Comment: In this case, it all depends on the implementation of your data export. If you share a sample, I will research it and share some advice.